# Differentiate the equation: $y = x{(1 + 3x)^5}$ using the product rule

Tags: calculus

After using the chain rule, I use the product rule and get dy/dx to be:

$15x{(1 + 3x)^4} + {(1 + 3x)^5}$

From then on I get stuck, i'm aware I need to expand and simplify further, but the answer in the textbook does this in a very easy manner that doesnt involve expanding brackets:

$\eqalign{
  &  = {(1 + 3x)^4} + (15x + 1 + 3x)  \cr 
  &  = {(1 + 3x)^4} + (1 + 18x) \cr} $

What is the reasoning behind this? What happens to the expression that goes to the power of 5?

Comment: Nitpick: you're not solving, you're differentiating. There's no unkown to find here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made an error in the second step.  The correct way to factor the expression is to note that both terms have a factor of $(1+3 x)^4$; the expression is then

$$(1+3 x)^4 (15 x + 1 + 3 x) = (1+3 x)^4 (1+ 18 x)$$

Comment: Sorry, could you explain why I've done it the wrong way? I'd like to understand, thank you.

Comment: You added, rather than multiplied, the common factor $(1+3 x)^4$.

Comment: @Assad: It's not that you made a mistake in the math. You simply copied wrong from the book.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have copied the textbook incorrectly, or there is a typo. That addition should be a multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

The product rule is $\dfrac{d(f(x)f(y))}{dx}=f(y)\dfrac{df(x)}{dx}+f(x)\dfrac{df(y)}{dx}$

let $f(x)=x $ and $g(x)=(1+3x)^5$

So use the rule and we can get the result

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=(1+3x)^5*1+x*5(1+3x)^4*3=(1+3x)^4(1+3x+15x)=(18x+1)(1+3x)^4$$